# Cannot replicate bootstrap sidebar arrow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create the 4th sidebar (from the left) using these [Bootstrap 5 examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/).

I am able to get everything except the arrow rotating when `aria-expanded=true`. I've tried different selectors, changing the aria labels but cannot get the arrow to rotate on expand.

The snippet is as follows:

```css
.btn-toggle-nav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0.1875rem 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.125rem;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.btn-toggle::before {
  width: 1.25em;
  line-height: 0;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='rgba%280,0,0,.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  transition: transform .35s ease;
  transform-origin: 0.5em 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-3">
  <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
    <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Collapsible</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
    <li class="mb-1">
      <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        Home
      </button>
      <div class="collapse" id="home-collapse">
        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Updates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mb-1">
      <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        Dashboard
      </button>
      <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse">
        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Overview</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Weekly</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Monthly</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Annually</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
    <li class="mb-1">
      <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        Account
      </button>
      <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse" style="">
        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">New...</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link-dark rounded">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `::before` pseudoelement is displayed `inline`. Add `display: inline-block` property:

```
.btn-toggle::before {
  width: 1.25em;
  line-height: 0;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='rgba%280,0,0,.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  transition: transform .35s ease;
  transform-origin: 0.5em 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```